# Jquery : identify mutiple handles on jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to do this :

1. make a jQuery slider with two handles
2. identify a handle when clicked
3. associate the color of a clicked handle to the color of a color-picker
4. Write a function which can add another handle to the slider
5. I tried this : 
   `

   $("#slider").delegate('.ui-slider-handle','click', function () {
   var handleNo=$(this).index(); 
   if (handleNo==0){ // code required //show a colorpicker whose selected color will be       the color of this handle }; 
   if (handleNo==1){ // code required //show a colorpicker whose selected color will be     the color of this handle }; }); 
   function addSliderHandle(){ // code required // this function will be able to add new     hanldes to above-mentioned slider // every new hanlde will also have the above     event attached }

`

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @GILL It may have helped to provide a reference to your previous question about the jquery slide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722712/jquery-identify-mutiple-handles-on-jquery-slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking at a Range Slider: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range

Could you also edit your question to answer the below?
 - When you say multiple, how many do you actually mean?
 - Are handles going to be added at Runtime?

Comment: handles to be added at runtime and same range slider as mentioned above. multiple means atleast two and maximum 10

Comment: I tried this code $("#sliderDiv").slider({
 orientation: 'vertical',
    min: 0,
    max: 100,    
    step: 1,
    values: [10, 90],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
            //$("input.sliderValue[data-index=" + i + "]").val(ui.values[i]);
        }
  $("input.sliderValue[data-index=0]").val(ui.values[0]);
  $("input.sliderValue[data-index=1]").val(ui.values[1]);
  colorStopTop=(ui.values[0]);
  colorStopBottom=(ui.values[1]);
  outputElelemnt="html";
  fillWithSelectedGrad();
  }//,

});

Comment: The above code gives me output of two different handles but I want to do some action specific to click on one particular handle

Comment: I want to 1. add different colors to individual slider handles 2. customize shape of each handle (use a CSS background or image)

Comment: @GILL, could you create a sample of your code on something like http://jsfiddle.net/ as that will give me an idea of your code and allow me to fine-tune the solution

Comment: Well I have two handles on one slider. I want to colorize each handle differently using a colorpicker. The action will be done on some event. Apologies for not posting code as have not been able to get a solution which I try.